# Analytics - Where do the parameters come from

Tags: url, analytics

Google Analytics provides me a list of called links of my website. 
I wonder where these requests came from and what they effect.

e.g. 
www.mywebsite.com/subpage/?ls=1 
www.mywebsite.com/subpage/?q=keyword 
www.mywebsite.com/subpage/?q=13123sdd

What does `?ls=1` and `?q=keyword`do? And where do they came from? Especially the keywords

Answer (score 1):

Those are GET parameters, and most commonly they come as a result of posting forms (or just by clicking on links with such URLs).

For (the most well-known) example, if you go to https://www.google.com and enter "test" and press Enter, you will go to a page `http://google.com/search?q=test` (with likely a bunch of other parameters as well). In a very simplified scenario, it would be because the box where you input your search string is an input element with `name="q"` contained in a form element with `method="GET" action="/search"`; when you submit the form (by pressing Enter), the browser will make the url by adding all the parameter to the form's action like this:

```
action?param1=value1&param2=value2...
```

or in this case, `/search?q=test`.

(In Google's specific case, this is not *actually* what is happening, because of various kinds of JavaScript magic that is normally going on; but that magic in the end does the same thing. But it *could*: if you turned off JavaScript on Google, then what I described would be exactly what would happen.)

As I said, you can submit that same URL literally, without having to go through a form. For example, you can click directly on this link to find some kittens: https://google.com/search?q=kittens

Parameters submitted with other methods than GET do not appear in URLs, and cannot be submitted merely by clicking a link, only through forms (which also support POST method) or JavaScript (which can submit any kind of method: GET, POST, or other methods not available to forms or links, like PUT, DELETE...)

As to what they *do*, nothing by themselves. They are interpreted by the `www.mywebsite.com` server, in any way they want. In Google's case, `q` is the query to search from, and what they *do* is give you (hopefully) relevant results to it. In `www.mywebsite.com`'s case? No idea. Could be anything.

Comment: Thank you very much!
But Im wondering because my website doesnt handle any GET parameters. So where do they came from? Do Crawler add them?

Comment: If your website doesn't handle them, they get ignored. They don't _do_ anything by themselves. And yes, crawlers could add them, or hackers looking for a way in, or people mistyping URLs. Anything, really.